# CraftCMS Redactor is adding <p> tags to viewable source code... but then removes them when saving

Tags: craft3, redactor

We are in the midst of a migration from WordPress to Craft.  Much of the content contains line breaks, which are converted to `<p>` tags in Redactor (as seen in Redactor's view source plugin).

But when the entry is saved (or previewed, as seen in the attached image), those `<p>` tags are stripped back out and never make it to the database.

Is there a config setting to "retain the automatically applied formatting from redactor when the entry is saved"? (we want to keep these styles that were temporarily added in by redactor)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Advanced section of your field definition, there are settings for clean-up actions and Purify HTML.

I suggest trying to disable Purify (or use a custom config).

Comment: Also, make sure you use the raw filter in your Twig template: `{{ entry.myRedactorField|raw }}`.

Comment: All those settings (Remove inline styles, Remove empty tags, Replace non-breaking spaces with regular spaces, Purify HTML) were turned off, and we are using the raw filter for the output.  The `<p>` tags are injected by javascript in redactor, but not sent forward to craft when the entry is saved.

Comment: I've also tried *with* all those settings checked... no difference

Comment: Here's what I found I can do as a workaround:

-open the entry in the control panel
-click preview -> content is bad (the <p> tags are in redactor, but not in the preview)
-add a line of plain text to the content
-click preview -> content is GOOD (and saves with newly added <p> tags)